# Save bitmap to Pictures folder (Xamarin Android)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, bitmap, xamarin.android

I have Xamarin Android app.

I try to save Linear layout like Bitmap . Here is code

```
 public void Save()
    {
        LinearLayout view = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.badge);

        view.DrawingCacheEnabled = true;
        view.BuildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap layout = view.GetDrawingCache(true);

    }
```

I need to save it to Pictures folder. How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

He explained the way to save bitmap as png in memory card with c #. I hope to understand your problem is correct.

"This here is a slim way to export a Bitmap as PNG-file to the sd-card using only C# stuff"

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29012075/6322661

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Canvas` to draw a `View` by the following code:

```
    public Bitmap createViewBitmap(View v)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(v.Width, v.Height,
                Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        v.Draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Linear layout is a kind of `View`. So you can create a Linear layout BitMap :

```
 View v = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.myLinearLayout);
 Bitmap myBitMap = createViewBitmap(v);
```

And then save it in the DCIM folder:

```
 public static void saveImage(Bitmap bmp)
 {
      try
      {
          using (var os = new System.IO.FileStream(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory + "/DCIM/Camera/MikeBitMap2.jpg", System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew))
           {
               bmp.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 95, os);
           }
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {

       }
   }
```

[image]

You can refer to my [github](https://github.com/mikexxma/SaveViewToBitMap) for the more code information.

Comment: Your code is great, I have one simple problem, I have this error

`Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0`

Comment: You may call `createViewBitmap(v)` in the `OnCreate`. This view does not draw completed. In my demo I call the function in the click event.

Comment: refer to answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/getwidth-and-getheight-of-view-returns-0 may help you to understand.