# To Insert an image in the gallery with a name, not a number

Tags: image, xamarin.android, insert, android-gallery

I used `Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.InsertImage(this.ContentResolver, bitmap, "MyTitleImage.png", null);` but the name of my bitmap is not `MyTitleImage.png` in gallery, it is a number (`1598086787328.jpg`).

Comment: I saw this link and my problem was solved. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25976002/saving-bitmap-to-file-xamarin-monodroid

Comment: Hi, if problem has been solved , remember to update solution in answer when you have time. It will be helpful for others who meet the same issue later. :-)

Comment: Hello. It has not solved my problem with InsertImage, but I solved my problem with an alternative solution.
What should I do now? Use that link at the end of my question?

Comment: Hi, if you think they are helpful to others, both can be updated in answer. It depends on you. :-)